# App icon not being created when i change the launcher activity from LoginActivity to Main2Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

When i change from Case 1 to Case 2 . The app icon is not being created, but the activity is running.

**CASE1:Manifest File When LoginActivity is launcher activity**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >


    </activity>


</application>
```

**CASE2:Manifest File When Main2Activity is launcher activity**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: what do you mean app icon is not being created?

Comment: there is no icon when i launch it in my phone using run. whereas when LoginActivity was the main launcher activity. The icon was being created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Activity and Application label should be same for the activity to have an icon created.

**EDIT CODE FOR CASE2:**

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".Main2Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".RegisterActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

</activity>
```